# Why is Spring KafkaTemplate implemented in an asynchronous way?

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

Why is Spring KafkaTemplate implemented in an asynchronous way? Do we have any other Spring implementation of it that is synchronous? I don't want to use `futureTask.get()` to make is seem synchronous

Answer (score 1):

You probably miss the fact that Spring for Apache Kafka is nothing more than convenient Spring-friendly API around standard Kafka Client. And that's already a `Producer.send()` API to return for us a `Future` making all the stack as asynchronous. So, even if someone would do a synchronous API for you it still would do that `futureTask.get()` underneath.

Comment: You can use the [Spring Integration Outbound Channel Adapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#si-outbound) which has a `sync` mode (it will wait for the future on your behalf).